# Showing that $F^*(L_{\mathbb{Y}}\omega)=L_{\mathbb{X}}(F^*\omega)$

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, derivatives, lie-algebras

Let $F:U \rightarrow V$ be a diffeomorphism between open sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $\mathbb{Y}$ be a vector field on $V$ and $\omega$ a $k$-form on $V$. Show that

$F^*(L_{\mathbb{Y}}\omega)=L_{\mathbb{X}}(F^*\omega)$

where $\mathbb{X}=F_*^{-1}\mathbb{Y}$

I have no idea how this could be done.

Comment: You could use Cartan's formula $$\mathcal{L}_X=\iota_X\circ d+d\circ \iota_X$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that, for any form $\omega$, $i_X(F^*\omega)=F^*(\iota_Y\omega)$. Hence, using the fact that $d$ commutes to $F^*$, and the Cartan formula,
\begin{eqnarray}
L_X(F^*\omega)&=&\iota_X(d(F^*\omega))+d(\iota_X(F^*\omega))\\
&=&\iota_X(F^*d\omega)+d(F^*\iota_Y\omega)\\
&=&F^*\iota_Y(d\omega)+F^*d(\iota_Y\omega)\\
&=&F^*(L_Y\omega)\,.
\end{eqnarray}
**EDIT.** To prove $i_X(F^*\omega)=F^*(\iota_Y\omega)$, you simply evaluate both sides on vector fields. Let $X_2,\dots,X_k$ be vector fields on $U$, then by definition
$$\Big(i_X(F^*\omega)\Big)(X_2,\dots,X_k)=(F^*\omega)(X,X_2,\dots,X_k)=\omega(Y,F_*X_2,\dots,F_*X_k)$$
and
$$\Big(F^*(\iota_Y\omega)\Big)(X_2,\dots,X_k)=(\iota_Y\omega)(F_*X_2,\dots,F_*X_k)=\omega(Y,F_*X_2,\dots,F_*X_k)$$
This proves the assertion.

Comment: Sorry I dont believe this is obvious, $i_X(F^*\omega)=F^*(\iota_Y\omega)$

Comment: Just plug in $k-1$ vector fields on both sides, and see for yourself.

Comment: I get that $i_X(F^*\omega)(v_{(1)},\dots,v_{(k-1)})=(F^*\omega)(\mathbb{X}, v_{(1)},\dots,v_{(k-1)})$ and $F^*(\iota_Y\omega)(v_{(1)},\dots,v_{(k-1)})=F^*(\omega(\mathbb{Y},v_{(1)},\dots,v_{(k-1)})$. I cant see how that identity can be shown/proved.